# Pagination stopped working on Django application

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am new to Django and I just picked up a book "Django 2 by example". I followed all the code in the tutorial bu something broke the pagination along the line and I just can't figure what it is. I get an output of **"Page of ."** instead of **"Page 1 of 1.** at the base of my blog. Find some of my code below:. P.S: Kindly ignore the indentation in the code. Thank you.

**Views.py**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
 from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
 from django.views.generic import ListView
 from django.core.mail import send_mail
 from django.db.models import Count
 from taggit.models import Tag
 from .models import Post, Comment
 from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm



 def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None`

    if tag_slug:
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
    object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
         posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
         posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
         posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
              'blog/post/list.html',
              {'page': page,
               'posts': posts,
               'tag' : tag})
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 <h1>My Blog</h1>
 {% if tag %}
 <h2>Posts tagged with "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
 {% endif %}
 {% for post in posts %}
 <h2>
  <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
    {{ post.title }}
  </a>
 </h2>
 <p class="tags">
  Tags:
  {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
    <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
      {{ tag.name }}
    </a>
    {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</p>
<p class="date">
  Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>
{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
 {% endfor %}
 {% include "pagination.html" with page=page_obj %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Pagination.html (template)**

```
<div class="pagination">
     <span class="step-links">
       {% if page.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
       {% endif %}
       <span class="current">
         Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages}}.
       </span>
         {% if page.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
         {% endif %}
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: in your view you are returning in context `'page': page` but it should be `'page': paginator`

Comment: I am still having same issue, even after returning 'page : paginator' as suggested. Is there something else I am not doing right? Thanks for your help.